# Using XMLWriter to generate XML File in PHP - outputMemory() function not working

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I am trying to create and write an **XML** file in PHP using **XMLWriter**.

My code is as follows:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('php://output');
$writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$writer->setIndent(4);
$writer->startElement('items');
$writer->startElement("main");
$writer->writeElement('user_id', 3);
$writer->writeElement('msg_count', 11);
$writer->endElement();
$writer->startElement("msg");
$writer->writeAttribute('category', 'test');
$writer->endElement();
$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
$writer->flush();

header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo $writer->outputMemory();
```

This seems to create valid XML onscreen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <main>
    <user_id>3</user_id>
    <msg_count>11</msg_count>
  </main>
  <msg category="test"/>
</items>
```

However when I try to echo the XML using:

```
echo $writer->outputMemory();
```

The output is blank, additionally when the XML file is created using:

```
$filename = "xml/example.xml";
$file = $writer->outputMemory();
file_put_contents($filename,$file);
```

The file contents are also blank.

How I am able to output the XML to the file? The `outputMemory()` function doesn't seem to be getting populated.

Comment: What if you do `openURI("xml/example.xml")` ?

Comment: No joy unfortunately, I am pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with that code

```
$filename = "xml/example.xml";
header("Content-Type: text/html/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xml");
```

and no longer use:

```
$filename = "xml/example.xml";
$file = $writer->outputMemory();
file_put_contents($filename,$file);
```

Pd: Sorry for my bad english.